# Sending push notification from device to all contacts

Tags: iphone, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I have an app where I would like to select a user in my contacts. If that person has my app installed, then I would like to send some data that is relevant for this app using a notification. The other user gets the notification, and acts on it within this app. Is that possible? I am thinking that if I can identify that users device, I can store this message in a server. When the user connects to the app, it will retrieve and get this users message from the server. But question is can I identify other devices like this, from my contact list. Can I send this notification using phone number instead of device id?

Please help.

Thank you,
Anks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot. You have to have the Apple Push Token for a device and the user has to have notifications turned on to be able to receive notifications from Apple Push.

You would need to maintain a server side database linking the APNS Token to a specific user account. There are a lot of dots to connect with this kind of implmentation. Your better bet would be maintaining a "list of contacts" within your App to link contacts to.

Comment: Thanks for reply. But do you think, i can send push notification to some selected users.